# Duplicate content site skipped in Yahoo and Bing

Tags: seo, content, bing

I want to buy a 1 year old site which my friend had initially created with duplicate content. In the later months he removed all such material and placed original stuff. Now it is in top charts in Google. But it is completely skipped by Yahoo and Bing.

Will it ever be able to come back in Yahoo and Bing given both give exactly same search results.

Answer (score 1):

It will just take time. The Bing crawler is notoriously slow at refreshing and updating old pages. Yahoo results are provided by Bing.

And obviously just because something is top in Google doesn't mean it will be top in Bing, or even rank well. Did you check that pages from your site are definitely indexed, by running `site:yoursite.com` in Bing?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I never look at Yahoo and Bing to bring me too much traffic. What I do instead is try to funnel traffic to my sites using Google, Twitter, Facebook, Youtube and many others. If your site is OK with Google, I think you can buy it because Yahoo and Bing don't bring you too much traffic.

I know that ignoring Y and B is maybe not so good on the long run, but as I see it, in the next 3-5 years Google will still be the most used Search Engine out there.

Comment: `Google will be the most used browser out there`? Surely you mean Chrome/Browser or, more likely google/search-engine. No?

Comment: Thanks Nate. I don't know what was in my mind when I wrote that answer. I edited it just now :)